# Tag set question sorting by "relevance"

Tags: feature-request, questions, tags, personalization

I want to request for a feature where I want a new tab in the tag sets questions page. This tab would be based on how many tags a particular question covers from the tags in my tag set. I know this might be a bit niche, but hey! What's wrong with having an extra tab?

Basically it is like I have a tag-set which covers 4 tags. Now I want the questions which contain maximum number of tags from the tag set to be higher in the list when compared to the ones that contain only 1 or 2 tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "tag set"? Your favorite tags?

Comment: tag set is a feature on SE that enables a user to view question from various tags(which are relevant to your expertise or interest) in a unified page.

Comment: screenshots might be good here

Comment: i dont think this feature requires a screenshot to explain